# SQL database is locked

Tags: c#, sqlite

I wanted to get the history of my browser that I faced this problem. 
The error that I get is for line `using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())` that show `Database is locked`.

BTW, I read relevant posts to my error and I still could not solve it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace CrawlHistory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select * From urls";
                    using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(dr[1].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is...Chrome...still running? Also in background...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti . No

Comment: Are you having a concurrent access to your database files? SQLite is not very good in dealing with it.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is, I had some problem to install the SQLite on my machine and I am not sure I did it in correct way.

Comment: I just tested your code, and it works,but...
Open your task manager check for chrome.exe process. Shut it down and it will work. 
There are some scenarios where after you close your Chrome browser it keeps some chrome.exe processes running.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It does not have any issue. You should be sure that you already closed the 'Chrome'. You can check it from the 'Task Manager'